# Replacing programs with batch issue

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to create auto-updater of my program.
In java part it looks like

```
int pid = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcessId();                    
String cmd = folder + "update.bat" + " " + currentLoc  + " " + updateLoc +  " " + Integer.toString(pid);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

And the batch contains

```
SET "name=GameDrive Logs Viewer.exe"
SET "myname=update.bat"
TASKKILL /pid %3
TASKKILL /pid %3
DEL "%1\%name%"
MOVE "%2\%name%" "%1"
"%1\%name%"
DEL "%2\%myname%"
```

So, I'm killing current program and delete it.
Then i move new version to old folder, run new version, and delete the bat file.
This bat file is perfectly works when i call it from cmd with sending parameters.
But nothing is happend when i'm trying use it from java program.
As i found, that all Dialog windows creating from current program have the same processID. (I tested it from another bat).
So, my guess is the batch which is called from my java program get the same processID and kill himself. 
Am I right? And if yes - can how I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need launch your `update.bat` in another `cmd` instance as follows (add path as necessary). In JAVA use `updatecall.bat` with next content:

Either with `CMD.exe`: [Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

```
cmd /C ""update.bat" %*"
```

or with `START`: [Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

```
start "" "update.bat" %*
```

If *start*ed a batch file then the command processor is run with the `/K` switch to `cmd.exe`. This means that the window will tend to remain after the batch has been run. To auto close it, add `EXIT` command to the end of *start*ed batch.

I'm sure there is a smarter solution without any auxiliary batch...